# Compile a userscript to a Safari and an Opera extension?

Tags: cross-browser, userscripts, safari-extension, browser-extension, opera-extension

I built a Greasemonkey userscript for Firefox and Chrome, and I now want to convert it to a Safari extension and an Opera extension.

Are there any compilers out there like [Arantius' Greasemonkey-to-extension compiler](https://arantius.com/misc/greasemonkey/script-compiler.php) but for Opera or Safari?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a good compiler for converting userscripts into Safari or Opera extensions.  Some userscripts work on Opera though, and there are some older Safari extensions that run some userscripts, but I don't hear good things about them.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look on http://kangoextensions.com/ it supports all the browsers you want. You can start with this post http://kangoextensions.com/blog/modifying-content-of-web-pages-using-jquery/ showing how you can create a content script and use jQuery in it.